# How can I add critical JS on Magento 2.3.3?

Tags: javascript, optimization, defer-js

Magento 2.3.3 has "**Move JS code to the bottom of the page**" function which moves all JS code to bottom of the page.

I need some JS code(Seal Verification Code which showing verification icon) not move to bottom.

**How can I do this?**

Comment: Do you want to configure different domain names or Ip address?

Comment: No I just need one JS file not move to bottom..

Answer (score 0):

There is a small but not recommended option to exclude certain scripts from being moved. However, this possibility may not be supported by all browsers. Moving the JavaScripts works in such a way that all `<script*</script>` tags are moved. Since upper and lower case is not considered here, you can avoid this with capital letters. Example:

```
<SCRIPT>yourscript</SCRIPT>
```